# Rectangle with a bottom arc cut in d3 js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

[image]

I was able to get only the rectangle. Not able to figure out how to produce the cut in the bottom?

```js
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'd3', 'data/server', 'css!app/css/vista'],function($, ko, d3, server){
 return {  
  activate: function(){
   
  },
  compositionComplete: function(){
   var self = this;      
   self.loadyourRank();
  },
  loadyourRank: function(){
   var data = [3];
   var width = 325, height = 430;
       
   var svgContainer = d3.select("#yourrank")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
   
   svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("width", 255)
    .attr("height", 340)
    .attr("fill", "#F2135D")
    .attr("stroke", "gray"); 
   
  }
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="yourrank" class="col-xs-4">
   <h4>Your Rank</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="bestrank" class="col-xs-8">
   <h4>Your Best Ranked Specialities</h4>
  </div>  
 </div>  
</div>
```

How to get the above shape or element in svg using d3.js ?? somebody help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SVG Path.

**`d` attribute calculation**

- Move to x,y
- Line to (x+width),y
- Line to (x+width),(y+height)
- Quadratic Bezier curve from current point to (x+width)/2,
  required_curve_height to x,(y+height)
- Close path (End point to Start point)

Refer [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) for more details.

> The SVG `<path>` element is used to draw advanced shapes combined from
>   lines, arcs, curves etc. with or without fill. The `<path>` element is
>   probably the most advanced and versatile SVG shape of them all.

```js
var data = [3];
var width = 325,
  height = 430;

var svgContainer = d3.select("#yourrank")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svgContainer.selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path") 
  .attr("d", "M 30,50 L 285,50 L 285,390 Q 157.5,200  30,390 Z")
  .attr("fill", "#F2135D")
  .attr("stroke", "gray");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourrank"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gilsha for the answer with perfect attributes.