# How to make rectangles arc/curved in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to make rectangles `curved` or `arched` `shaped`. Here is my `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/y8pthz2x/ . I want to make these rectangles over radar chart axis arc/curved using `d3`

Comment: it may be a case where you just want to check out the raw SVG syntax instead of relying on d3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths. you can still use the d3 APIs for creating the SVG though.

Comment: @paradite I was thinking the same , `curved line` rather as a solution to this. But not sure how to generate these 3 coordinates for each `curved line`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909931/rectangle-with-a-bottom-arc-cut-in-d3-js for an example

Comment: @paradite yes so they are using `path` not `rectangles` , actually I was assuming if any way is there  to curve `rectangles`

Comment: updated my answer with some explanations

Comment: @paradite thanks a lot , I am trying to understand `M`,`L`,`Q` concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jrxdbctz/5/

---

intermediate steps:
Just one arc:
https://jsfiddle.net/jrxdbctz/2/

Reversing x and y for a different style:
https://jsfiddle.net/jrxdbctz/3/

Bar with width:
https://jsfiddle.net/jrxdbctz/4/

---

Example of drawing an arc using d3.js (adapted from [Rectangle with a bottom arc cut in d3 js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909931/rectangle-with-a-bottom-arc-cut-in-d3-js)):

```js
var data = [3];
var width = 325,
  height = 430;

var svgContainer = d3.select("#yourrank")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svgContainer.selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path") 
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
    var x0 = 0;
    var x1 = 200;
    var y1 = 50; 
    var y2 = 100;
    var k= parseFloat((x0+x1)/2); 
    return "M " + x0 +","+y1+" Q "+k+","+ (y1-100) +" " + x1 + ","+y1 
    + "L " + x1 +","+y2+" Q "+k+","+ (y2-100) +" " + x0 + ","+y2
    + " Z"; 
  })
  .attr("fill", "#F2135D")
  .attr("stroke", "gray");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourrank"></div>
```

`M`= moveto

`L` = lineto

`Q` means:

> The other type of Bezier curve that is available is a quadratic Bezier, Q. It's actually a simpler curve than the cubic one: it requires one control point only, which determines the slope of the curve at both the start point and the end point. It takes two arguments: the control point and the end point of the curve.

For more documentations on how `M` `Q` `L` works you will need to consult 
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: My hunch OP wants the bar chart on the spider chart to be curved...shown in the fiddle he shared.

Comment: @Cyril you are correct I want the `bar charts`  `(rectangles)` on the axis to be `curved` or `arc`

Comment: @DibyenduDutta like this? http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect4

Comment: @paradite like this http://art.tenfab.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DimensionalCurvedTaperedRectangleWall_T.png

Comment: @DibyenduDutta oh i see. yeah, I guess then you just need to find that middle control point for bezier curve. you can use a fixed y coordinate and make x coordinate with respect to your data. Shouldn't be hard to find examples or code it yourself.

Comment: @DibyenduDutta this is the correct way to do it. You have to change the rect to a path, rect's don't cater for curved edges

Comment: @paradite yes you are correct . will try to implement the same. Help in case I am stuck :)

Comment: @paradite I got the idea but still not able to understand the formula of setting `Q` . I have tried with only `M` and `Q` (manually ) to draw a simple curved line which is working

Comment: @paradite is there any formula or calculation logic exists to calculate for `M` `starting point  (Move to)` which input I only have , can calculate the rest `coordinates `

Comment: @DibyenduDutta I think you already have the 4 coordinates of the corners. So u just need to calculate the midpoint and put those numbers into the path's d attribute.

Comment: not Sure @paradite I am saying for `1` bar I have only  `x` ,` y` cordinates.  I am trying for 1 curved line  for the time being . Does this code make sense `combos.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr('key', function (d) {
    return d.key1;
  })
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('val', function(d) {
   return d.height1 < 0 ? r + d.height1 : r;
  })  
  .attr("d",function(d) {
   var y1 = this.getAttribute('val');
   var k= parseFloat((-w+285)/2);
   return "M "+-w+","+y1+" Q "+k+","+-w+" 285,"+y1+"" ;
   
  });`

Comment: I have tried this actually let me share the `jsfiddle` but not working .Why you are not trying on my fiddle please

Comment: can you show me a jsfiddle where you implemented my method? i can take a look.

Comment: @DibyenduDutta fixed the syntax problems for you:https://jsfiddle.net/jrxdbctz/ your `this.getAttribute('val')` returns 0 for most data, you might want to check that.

Comment: Yes because `r` value is `0` , if you check my first fiddle then you can see the `y`  co-ordinate value for most of `bars` is `0` , thats what coming here.

Comment: But compare to my first `fiddle` this solution looks complete different right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110635/discussion-between-paradite-and-dibyendu-dutta).